# Are there works composed in Quenya or Sindarin by people other than Tolkien himself?

Tags: tolkien-elvish

Are there any works composed (e.g., peoms, songs, short stories) in either Quenya or Sindarin by other authors than JRR Tolkien himself?

I am already aware of some dialogues in the *Lord of the Rings* films, these do not count here as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [*Pater Noster in Quenya*](http://www.elvish.org/articles/Attolma.html)
- [*Poems in Quenya*](http://www.elvish.org/gwaith/arandil.htm)
- [*Some more poems in Quenya*](http://www.istad.org/tolkien/poetry.html)
- [*Pater Noster in Sindarin*](https://www.elfdict.com/phrases/1-sindarin/16-lords_prayer#!605) (JRRT for comparison)
- [*Pater Noster in Sindarin*](http://www.elvish.org/gwaith/sindarin.htm)
- [*Poems & Stories in Sindarin*](http://valarguild.org/varda/Tolkien/encyc/lang/tranS/translationS/transTitlesS.htm)
- [*Poem in Sindarin*](https://steemit.com/poetry/@katrina-ariel/a-poem-in-sindarin-the-language-of-lord-of-the-rings)

**NB: I am not competent to guarantee that any of these works are "correct" or "grammatical", with the exception of JRRT's submission.**

Comment: I have to point out that the "Pater Noster in Sindarin" is written by Tolkien himself, and is therefore "correct" but not answering the question.

Comment: @杨Eugene -- Hopefully the edit helps!

Comment: Thanks, it does!